# Android Studio SQL/Java - retrieving data from separate view

Tags: java, android

title couldn't specifically identify my issue so i'll get right to it. Essentially, i have an an app comprise of several activities, one of them being a simple mock-up game, that once completed allows user's to enter their name to save to a high-score list database that will be retrieved within a separate activity, but i'm having immense problems getting this to work. I understand the logic of it, and i can successfully implement it all into a single activity to test if name's are being added correctly, but i just can't manage to retrieve the database entries correctly from my second activity (it's giving me an error stating i'm attempting to reference a null object, so i assume i haven't implemented something properly in one of my activities).

Here is the partial program code from my game activity relevant to the dialogue box

```
 builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                "No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FourthActivity.this);
                                        builder.setTitle("Enter name for high-score list:");

// Set up the input
                                        final EditText input = new EditText(FourthActivity.this);
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                                        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                                        builder.setView(input);

// Set up the buttons
                                        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                inputName = input.getText().toString();
                                                SQLiteDatabase db = myOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                                values.put("name", inputName);
                                                int intScore = Integer.parseInt(theScore);
                                                values.put("score", theScore);

                                                db.insert(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                                                startActivity(new Intent(FourthActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

                                            }
                                        });
                                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                                        builder.show();

                                    }
                                });

                        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                        alert11.show();
```

And here is the program for my SecondActivity, which is meant to display my high-score list:

```
CustomOpenHelper myOpenHelper;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);




            displayDataInTable();







}


void displayDataInTable(){

    List<String> values = queryTable();

    if (values != null) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SecondActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }




}

List<String> queryTable() {
    List<String> player = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = myOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        int score = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("score"));
        player.add(id + " --> the player " + name + " has a score of " + score +"s");

    }

    return player;
}
```

Hopefully i made my problems clear, and thanks for any help provided! I'm still completely new to Android programming, so i'm syntax is probably a bit all over the place.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace and point out where exactly (which line) the nullpointerexception occurs?

Comment: In second activity have you initialized myOpenHelper? Please check, I guess that line is throwing error

Comment: if you haven´t forgot anything to post, your `myOpenHelper` is not initialized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you did not create object for the SqliteOpenHelper class i.e. CustomOpenHelper using new operator.if we create an object without new operator the customOpenHelper object will be null.Without using new operator customOpenHelper acts as a reference.

Add this in your **FourthActivity** before calling **myOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()**

```
myOpenHelper = new CustomOpenHelper();   
SQLiteDatabase db = myOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

In **SecondActivity** add the below code

```
myOpenHelper = new CustomOpenHelper();
SQLiteDatabase db = myOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Its a good practice try to access SQliteOpenHelper class by passing context